# Website is slow without https

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, performance, ubuntu-12.04

As you can see, http://coinad.com/ is slow, and https://coinad.com/ is fast.
I've upgraded the server, reviewed the code, optimized the tables and anything seems to work.

This is driving me mentally insane.

Is there any config file that limits the usage of server resources for http and https independently? When I run htop everything seems to be fine, low RAM usage, and all 4 CPU cores aren't under heavy stress.

EDIT

The site has a lot of traffic, but the server should handle it well, it has 8 GB RAM and 4 CPU cores (digitalocean.com).

Comment: Give us _something_ to work with here! Your Apache configuration, what you have tried so far, etc.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Here it is (apache2.conf): http://pastebin.com/eXsSEcER

Comment: can you add the site configurations for both http and https from /sites-enabled/  ? 

fwiw, I tested the two links you gave and get really inconsistent response times from both http and https. anywhere from 0.3 seconds up to 2.5 seconds, neither appearing to be better than the other.

Comment: @Zeb Please try again with the new links, there's a noticeable difference. Do you mean the VirtualHosts?

Comment: wow, that's pretty bad.... yes, lets take a look the virtual hosts.

Comment: interesting that the text links you had up first weren't showing the same behavior.     are there any load balancers, or reverse proxies in the mix?   is the http site getting significantly more traffic than the https?

Comment: VirtualHosts: http://pastebin.com/qzKfJNmK If you test now you'll see that even the text files is now showing the same behavior. No, the traffic is balanced between the https and http, even though I don't understand how that makes any difference since it's all the same server.

Comment: ok, a bit more digging...   can you post the output of apachectl -V
and apachectl status

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/64UVWUUV

Answer (score 0):

After looking over everything you've posted, I do have some suggestions, but as to why your HTTP is much, much slower than your HTTPS, I don't have a solid answer for you. I do have some strong suspicions, but without some more detailed knowledge of your environment, setup, code, etc. I can't say with any confidence what the problem is. That being said, your setup needs tuned, I highly suspect once tuned, your problem will disappear.

Specifically, it looks like you're using most of the defaults in the apache server settings. If your code/stack will allow you to switch to worker MPM vs prefork, I'd suggest it. Then read up on and tune your max clients, spare servers and everything else in those blocks.   I also see a ton of keepalives in your apache status, given it had been restarted 3 minutes prior that's a lot of keepalives, I'd crank the those settings down to really low timeouts. You've got a fair amount of resources on that box, setup apache correctly and it should preform fine under moderate loads.

Speaking of apache, use nginx. Seriously, using nginx either as the primary web server or as a reverse proxy/cache and ssl endpoint is one of the best things you can ever do for website performance.

Good luck.